# PHP to query table with where statment column names defined by array

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query that returns 2 arrays they can have anywhere from 0 to 5 results for each array. i need to take the results of the array and use them to run a second query where the columns in the where statment are assigned by the array

here is the base code

```
$result = $conn->query("SELECT UsedQty,NewQty FROM Legend where Name like '$Use%'");
 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

 $UsedQty[$g]=$row['UsedQty'];
  $NewQty[$g]=$row['NewQty'];
  $g++;

         }


$result = $conn->query("select * from remainder where po = '$po' and
(($UsedQty[0]>0 or $UsedQty[1]>0 or $UsedQty[2]>0) or 
($NewQty[0]>0 or $NewQty[1]>0 or $NewQty[2]>0)) limit $cnt,1");
```

and as long as there are values for all of the variable is works, but if there are only 1 or 2 (or 0) values for the array it will not work

i have also tried

```
     $result = $conn->query("select * from remainder where po = '$po' and
($UsedQty[$g]>0)  limit $cnt,1");
```

it has to be done in a single query as the variable $cnt is keeping track of records and order---closed system so security injections are not an issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pad the arrays with the desired number of elements before executing the query. Something like this might do the trick:

```
while ($g  < [desired_count]) {
    array_push($UsedQty,0);
    array_push($NewQty,0);
    $g++;
}
```

The `[desired_count]` should be set to the number of elements that will be tested in the WHERE clause.

It is not apparent how the query will return 0-5 rows, (based on "*2 arrays [that] can have anywhere from 0 to 5 results for each array*"). The query will return 1 array; the `while` loop creates 2 arrays. Perhaps this `($UsedQty[0]>0 or $UsedQty[1]>0 or $UsedQty[2]>0)` is a typing shortcut and the intention is to test 5 values? In that case `[desired_count]` will be 5.

Comment: you know that you are a probably using a JS syntax? at least it is not PHP

Comment: It's hard to keep track of 6 languages!! thanks for pointing that out...corrected. I hope it reverses the downvote.

Comment: the issue is the desired count is never know before hand--the SELECT UsedQty,NewQty FROM Legend where Name like '$Use%' returns values that range from 0-5 for both used and new qty

Comment: Answer is modified.  I used a placeholder for the desired count is because "the query returns 0-5 rows" did not match the "WHERE" clause which only tests 3 values. Does the number of rows returned vary based on the `Name like` clause? How many elements will be tested in the `WHERE`? (Suggest you modify the question with this information because it would materially change the approach).